# BufferedReader reading garbage

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

I'm using BufferedReader to read some HEX dumps. But BufferedReader reads garbage values before the actual contents of the file.

Example:

Actual file contents looks like this (if I open it with an editor like vim):

```
02e9 9000 e890 0000 815e 08ee eb01 201a
754f 2072 6170 7473 6920 2073 6f20 7275
6620 7475 7275 2165 8b20 e9ee 018a 0000
```

What BufferedReader reads looks like this:

```
���Bud1������������á�����������������������������������������������������������E�v�i�l�.�c�������������������������������������������R�i�o�.�E�v�i�l�.�c�o�m�.�h�e�xIlocblob������F���(���ˇˇ����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������� �����
�@������Ä��������������������������������� ������@������Ä����������������������������������� ������@������Ä����������������������������������� ������@�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������E���á�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������DSDB����������������������������� ���`�������������������������������������������� ������@������Ä����������������������������������� ������@������Ä����������������������������������� ������@��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
02e9 9000 e890 0000 815e 08ee eb01 201a
754f 2072 6170 7473 6920 2073 6f20 7275
6620 7475 7275 2165 8b20 e9ee 018a 0000
```

I don't understand what's happening. The first line contains part of the name of the file. Is there some meta-data that doesn't actually appear in the file. How do I ignore this?

My code snippet is pretty standard File I/O:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

String line = input.readLine();

while(line != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
  line = input.readLine();
}
```

Comment: How do you know that that is the actual contents of the file? Are you sure you're reading the correct file?

Comment: Actual contents of file is what I see if I open the file in vim.

Comment: What about if you use `head` (to show the first few lines of the file) instead of `vim`?

Comment: `head` returns the same

Comment: You shouldn't use BufferedReader/FileReader to read hex dumps. Those classes assume proper character encoding.

Comment: @dejuknow as far as I know hex dumps are always extremely conservative in the characters they contain

Comment: I still get the correct contents. It's just that there's a bunch of garbage in front of it.

Comment: It makes me want to listen to ska.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. In OS X, a hidden folder `.DS_Store` exists in the directory. I was mass reading HEX dumps, so that file was included which led to the garbage values.

Comment: If you had included more code in your question, this might have been more obvious.